# PHP tag inside a PHP tag, is there an alternative?

Tags: php, html

I wanted to echo a bunch of html code if a user is on a specific rank. but I get an error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

PHP Code

```
<?php if ($row['rank'] == 0) { echo '

//SOME CODE HERE
                                <label>Question 1: </label>
<input class="au-input au-input--full" style="width: 50%;" type="text" name="question1" placeholder="Question 1" value="' . $question1 . '"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1multiple"' <?php if(isset($_POST['q1multiple'])) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> '>
<label>Allow more than one answer </label>
</div>

//SOME CODE HERE
end of echo';} ?>
```

The error is in the if(isset($_POST['q1multiple'])) { echo "checked='checked'" part.

What should I do with it?

Comment: What is `some code` PHP or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do an `PHP` tag inside an `PHP`-tag.
Try it with an short-if command like:
`(isset($_POST['q1multiple']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')`

Here an fix of your code:

```
<?php if ($row['rank'] == 0) { echo '

//SOME CODE HERE
                                <label>Question 1: </label>
<input class="au-input au-input--full" style="width: 50%;" type="text" name="question1" placeholder="Question 1" value="' . $question1 . '"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="q1multiple"' . (isset($_POST['q1multiple']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . '>
<label>Allow more than one answer </label>
</div>

//SOME CODE HERE
end of echo';} ?>
```

Comment: This solves the problem but the explanation is not what the problem is

Comment: This one worked! Thank you so much. 
Can someone explain to me whats the "?" and ": ' ')" means that fix? So I could learn as well. :)

Comment: @James Ocampo it's called a "ternary operator". You can find info about it in the PHP docs. It's basically a short way of writing a simple "if" statement

Answer (score 1):

You should learn basics of PHP, you are inside an `echo`, don't open `<?php` again, just use :

```
<input type="checkbox" 
     name="q1multiple"
     '. (isset($_POST['q1multiple'])) ? "checked='checked" : '') .'
>
```

It's only string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, I created the html code outside an echo, and decided to put it inside an echo, my bad. Thank you for this.